# Not able to use ascii space in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a program which will unhide the folder in USB.
Sometime when there is virus in pc,All the data get hide in folder name " "(ASCII Space),with attribute system and Hidden.When i type the command

```
attrib " " -h -s
```

in cmd ,it undo the hide and system attribute ,But when i type the same command using a bat file it shows error

```
G:\>attrib "á" +h +s
File not found - á
```

Comment: Apparently you typed something that's not an ASCII space. Anyway it's not a valid name for a file/directory so maybe you can't fix it via a batch file?

Comment: it is valid,you can try  alt+0160 when renaming your file.

Comment: that's a different character: nonbreaking space with a different code is not an ASCII space (0x20 or 32).

Comment: Your batch file is probably saved in a different encoding (UTF8? UTF-16 Unicode?) that differs from the default system encoding (which is probably codepage 430 or 850). Anyway if the file has really just a single ASCII space (0x20, 32) in its name then I doubt a batch file would be able to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. **Proof**: to reproduce the problem, **copy & paste** next code snippet into an open `cmd` window (not into a batch file):

```
echo OFF
chcp 1250
echo(dir /B /S /A " ">33782406.bat
33782406.bat
echo no-break space 0xA0 = Alt+0160>" "
type 33782406.bat
33782406.bat

chcp 852
type 33782406.bat
33782406.bat
echo ON
```

**Output**:

```
==> echo OFF
chcp 1250
Active code page: 1250
echo(dir /B /S /A " ">33782406.bat
33782406.bat
File Not Found
echo no-break space 0xA0 = Alt+0160>" "
type 33782406.bat
dir /B /S /A " "
33782406.bat
D:\bat\UnASCII Names\ 

chcp 852
Active code page: 852
type 33782406.bat
dir /B /S /A "á"
33782406.bat
File Not Found
echo ON

==>
```

**Conclusion**: run your script using appropriate code page (character set), the same as saved batch file encoding (Windows Notepad's `ANSI` comports with e.g. `CP1250` or `CP1252` depending on your locale settings, see also `charmap` tool).

Next image illustrates that `" "` copied from your original code line is not ASCII space.

[image: no-break space]

Comment: how i can solve this issue now ?,how to run script using appropriate code page?

Comment: @JatinAsija please note `chcp` command in my answer. Maybe `chcp 1252` and then `script.bat`. Maybe (not sure) `chcp 1252&script.bat`...